# Dynamically merging values to object properties - first is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, javascript-objects

I have a php generated javascript code which adds attributes and values dynamically to an object. It looks something like this:

```
 var javascriptObject = {};

 <?php
 foreach($events as $event)
      echo 'javascriptObject[$event->date] += $event->title';
 endforeach
 ?>
```

Since I might have multiple events on the same date, it would add to the same object property, which is then processed by an external calendar library. Now, everything works fine. BUT, since it adds new data with += the first "undefined" value always stays in the beginning of every entry.

My question is, is there a way in Javascript to initialize an object with a default (empty or maybe null) value instead of leaving it 'undefined'? Can someone point me to a better solution?

ps: I'd really like to avoid checking for 'undefined' at every loop to keep the code clean, since it's a php generated javascript, would be a complete mess when the event list is big.

Comment: Variables are not expanded inside single quotes, only inside double quotes.

Comment: this is just an example of the logic, syntax might not be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with:

```
foreach ($events as $event) {
  echo 'javascriptObject[' . $event->date . '] = (javascriptObject[' . $event->date . '] || "") + "' . $event->title . '";';
}
```

Or even saver way:

```
$javascriptObject = array();
foreach ($events as $event) {
  if ( !isset($javascriptObject[ $event->date ]) ) {
    $javascriptObject[ $event->date ] = '';
  }
  $javascriptObject[ $event->date ] .= $event->title;
}

echo 'var javascriptObject = ' . json_encode($javascriptObject) . ';';
```

Comment: You're not appending to the property if it already exists, you're overwriting it.

Comment: the problem wasn't the syntax.. I'm using laravel so the syntax written was just an example

Comment: @RaphaelCabrera My second example does everything in PHP - after that you should just create and pring JSON object.

Comment: If I use the first code, it still appends "undefined" to the beginning of every entry.

Comment: Second code works. Just for learning reasons, would there be a way to not append the 'undefined' in the beginning using the first code?

Comment: @RaphaelCabrera The first code gives `undefined` because in the first time you access the variable, it converts `undefined` "state" to the string and appends to it next value. If you test if it's not undefined or put `""` empty string otherwise - it will work.